# set linux alias with background mode and multiple commands

Tags: linux, alias

I set the following linux alias command in `.bashrc`, but it does not work. 
Could some one tell me how to set it?

```
alias svngui='cd /home/personal_folders/j.jia/jhy_bin/WorkBench-1.6.8/Source; sh wb.sh&; cd -'
```

Comment: "does not work" - need more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will produce a syntax error which says "syntax error near unexpected token `;'".
You need to enclosed your command with parentheses like this (sh wb.sh &);

So you can include your alias in .bashrc like this:

alias svngui='cd /home/personal_folders/j.jia/jhy_bin/WorkBench-1.6.8/Source; (sh wb.sh&); cd -'

Answer (score 2):

Use parentheses in your alias:

```
alias foo='cd /dir/one ; (command &) ; cd /other/dir'
```

If it is okay to have `wb.sh` to be executed in a subshell. Redirect the output of `command` (`sh wb.sh` in your case) as needed.

Answer (score -1):

You need either `&` or `;`, `&;` is invalid.

Use `&`.

Comment: Thanks your reply. But I really want run wb.sh in background mode. Is there other alternative way to reach my goal?

Comment: I think you misunderstood something.